# Set size of boost::shared_array after declaration

Tags: c++

I have at the beginning of the code `boost::shared_array<uint8_t> buffer(new uint8_t[fileSize]);`. I want to change that as `size` will be read from a file. Therefore, how can I just declare `boost::shared_array<uint8_t> buffer` and allocate the size after I read it?

I am reading the file with:

```
    size_t fileSize;
    union size{
        uint8_t size_arr[4];
        uint32_t size;
    } size;
    if (myfile.is_open()){
        while ( getline (myfile,line) ){
            if(lineNum==1)
                size.size_arr[0] = strtoul(line.c_str(), 0 , 16);
            if(lineNum==2)
                size.size_arr[1] = strtoul(line.c_str(), 0 , 16);
            if(lineNum==3)
                size.size_arr[2] = strtoul(line.c_str(), 0 , 16);
            if(lineNum==4) {
                size.size_arr[3] = strtoul(line.c_str(), 0 , 16);
                fileSize = size.size;
                //boost::shared_array<uint8_t> buffer(new uint8_t[stringFromFile_size]); //CANNOT be done here
            }
            if(lineNum>=5)
                size.size_arr[lineNum-1] = strtoul(line.c_str(), 0 , 16);
            lineNum++;
        }

        myfile.close();
    }
```

Of course if I declare it in the if for `lineNum==4` I cannot use `buffer` outside the while loop which is the goal.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> buffer; // note []
// std::shared_ptr<uint8_t[]> buffer; 

// get size 
size_t sz = ...;

buffer.reset(new uint8_t[sz]); // allocate memory
```

Comment: Why the need to change to unique or shared ptr? Can't it be declared as `boost::shared_array<uint8_t[]> buffer;` and then `buffer.reset`?

Comment: @aripod because they are standard and `shared_array` is just the reminiscent of back when pre-standard `shared_ptr` couldn't handle arrays if I recall correctly.

Comment: @aripod `shared_array::reset` would also work, but I recommend you use `unique_ptr`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. However, it requires c++ 11.